# SSRS 2019 not available/working

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I installed 2019 SSRS on 2019 SQL Server and after I configured everything in the configuration manager, I can't see the services for SSRS under sql server config manager and also when I tried to run reports (go to the reports URL), this is what I get:

> **The service is not available.**
>
> The report server isn’t configured properly. Contact your system administrator to resolve the issue. System administrators: The report server can’t access or use the encryption key. You might need to add the server to the scale-out group, reimport encrypted content, or delete all encrypted content and generate a new encryption key.'

Why is this happening? What does this entail to? - 'The report server can’t access or use the encryption key. You might need to add the server to the scale-out group, reimport encrypted content, or delete all encrypted content and generate a new encryption key.'

---

I ran in Powershell `Get-Service -Name SQLServerReportingServices` and it showed:

| Status | Name | DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Running | SQLServerReport... | SQL Server Reporting Services |

I still want to figure out why I can't access the URL and that error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you migrated SSRS repository?
Based on the error message SSRS cannot decrypt encrypted content so just do what it proposed

- [restore encrypted key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-back-up-and-restore-encryption-keys)
- [Delete encrypted content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-encryption-keys-delete-and-re-create-encryption-keys) - usually it's passwords in data sources.

Comment: I didn't migrate, I built a new fresh 2019 VM and installed SQL Server 2019 and migrated my databases from my old 2016 sql server to the new 2019 sql server, and installed new SSRS 2019 on the new server. Linked the migrated database to the newly built SSRS and that's how I got the error.

Comment: When you installed new SSRS you set use existing repository database or create new? If you use existing database - you performed migration and need to restore encryption key to decrypt the passwords. Or delete all passwords and modify data sources manually

Comment: Yes, I migrated the 2016 database (existing db) to the new 2019 sql server. Is there a step where I can restore the encryption key to decrypt the passwords?

Comment: Check the first link in my answer. If old server is available, run Report Server Configuration Manager and press button backup encryption keys. On new server run - restore encryption key and point to file from step one

Comment: Thanks for the info, so I actually did that step earlier but however since this was an existing db it had the previous server's key and that was causing the issue. I went ahead and did these configs in ssms
`
USE ReportServer;
GO
-- To backup the keys
SELECT * 
INTO KeysTempBackup
FROM dbo.Keys;
GO

-- To confirm
SELECT * FROM dbo.Keys;
SELECT * FROM KeysTempBackup

-- Remove the old key
USE ReportServer;
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.Keys
WHERE InstanceName='MSSQLServer';
GO `

Once you did this then you can backup and restore the encryption key.
Many thanks for your help :)